# two identical mysql-databases - one uses indizes, the other don´t

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two identical databases on two different servers.

On the first one a join of three tables goes very fast, EXPLAIN shows the use of indexes. MySQL 5.6.28 and PHP 5.3 running

On the second one, with the exactly same database - but php 7 and mysql 5.7.15 - the Indexes are not used.

I´m confused! Why can´t the second server use the indexes?

Comment: If you are running the `explain` on the DB the PHP is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe it *can* use them but statistics says it's not worth it.

Comment: If you think indexes should be used, try  ANALYZE TABLE

Comment: Is there any error when you are trying to create indexes on second DB?